# Opening a Bootstrap Modal on mouse release with jQuery Selectable

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using jquery-selectable to select multiple table cells. Each table cell has a data-date attribute with a date for each cell. I would like to open a bootstrap modal window after the selection has been made with the data-date values in the modal window. Here is the HTML I am working with and jQuery code I have so far:

```
<tr class="selectable">
    <th class="user-blue">J. Doe 123456</th>
    <td class="ui-state-default" data-date="12-12-2015" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">12</td>
    <td class="ui-state-default" data-date="12-23-2015" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">12</td>
    <td class="ui-state-default" data-date="1-02-2016" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">24</td>
    <td class="ui-state-default" data-date="1-12-2016" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">24</td>
    <td class="ui-state-default" data-date="12-11-2015" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">N/A</td>
    etc...
</tr>
```

And here is the javascript so far:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".selectable" ).selectable();
  });

$(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal({
        keyboard: true,
        backdrop: "static",
        show:false,
    }).on('show', function(){ //subscribe to show method
        var date = $(event.target).closest('td').data('data-date');
        $(this).find('.modal-body').html($('<b>dates selected: ' + date  + '</b>'))
    });
});
```

Here is the jsFiddle URL http://jsfiddle.net/jeffcc/uwb6pbpk/

The issue is that the modal doesn't open at all after I've selected a few cells and second, since I have no been able to get far enough, I have not been able to show the data-date values.

How can I get the modal to open after I've selected a few cells?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with data-date not displaying is that the data() selector does not require the data- prefix so the following should work for that:

```
    var date = $(event.target).closest('td').data('date');
```

and the problem with it not displaying correctly could be that you are initialising the modal twice, once as would normally be done by the data tags then yourself. Try:

```
$('#myModal').on('show', function(){ //subscribe to show method
    var date = $(event.target).closest('td').data('data-date');
    $(this).find('.modal-body').html($('<b>dates selected: ' + date  + '</b>'))
});
```

Do you have a jsfiddle or working example so I could have a closer look?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=5K51k3Jqzx is the jsFiddle. It's not that it's not displaying correctly, it's just not opening at all after I've selected a few cells.

Comment: Sorry, that's the incorrect fiddle, this is the proper fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jeffcc/uwb6pbpk/ I have updated the question with the fiddle link